# I have a problem with finding end of string in assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, strlen

the code:

```
.text
_start: .global _start
        mov r2, #0
        adr r1, msg
        ldrb r5, =newline
getlen:
        ldrb r3, [r1,r2]
        add r2, r2, #1
        cmp r3, r5
        bne getlen
p:
        mov r0, #1
        mov r7, #4
        swi 0
exit:
        mov r0, #0
        mov r7, #1
        swi 0
newline:
        .byte '\0'
msg:
        .asciz "Print Me If you can!\n"
.end
```

The purpose of this code is get the length of msg and print msg with it.
But when i debug this, register 2(which has the info of length) does not have correct answer. I think it can't catch end of the string character. Any advice?

Comment: You say that r2 does not have the correct answer, but you don't say (1) what the correct answer is, or (2) what incorrect value is in `r2`. Use a debugger to step through the program one instruction at a time. Keep an eye on the values in the registers to see where the count goes wrong.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for comment. with your advice I check that I was having problem with indexing string to character(line 7) so i changed it to
`ldrb r3, [r1, #1] !` 
But problem is if i change newline's content('\0' to 'a') it still works.
It mus print out "Print Me If you c" but all string.

Comment: `ldrb r5, =newline` sets `r5` to the address of a symbol.  (Where you have a `0` byte, not a newline).  You're comparing characters from the string (zero-extended to 32-bit) against that address.  Don't do that, `mov r5, #0` or better `cmp r3, #0`.  If you single step with a debugger and look at register values, it should be easy to see why `bne getlen` is always taken.